# Where's the difference between these two VLC codec identifiers?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I converted a `.ts` file to `.mp4` using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i hls-360p.ts -codec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc hls-360p.mp4
```

Altough no reencoding was intended, VLC states a just slightly different video codec string:

- Input `.ts` file: `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(h264)`
- Output `.mp4` file: `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1)`

**What's the difference?**

---

Input file screenshot:

[image: Input file screenshot]

---

Output file screenshot:

[image: Output file screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [H.264 Video Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808(v=vs.85).aspx),

`avc1` indicates H.264 bitstream without start codes

> The MP4 container format stores H.264 data without start codes.
>   Instead, each NALU is prefixed by a length field, which gives the
>   length of the NALU in bytes. The size of the length field can vary,
>   but is typically 1, 2, or 4 bytes.

And `h264` indicates H.264 bitstream with start codes.

> H.264 bitstreams that are transmitted over the air, or contained in
>   MPEG-2 program or transport streams, or recorded on HD-DVD, are
>   formatted as described in Annex B of ITU-T Rec. H.264. According to
>   this specification, the bitstream consists of a sequence of network
>   abstraction layer units (NALUs), each of which is prefixed with a
>   start code equal to 0x000001 or 0x00000001.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Gyan's answer, the size of the length field is called NALULengthSizeMinusOne and is present in the avCc part of the avc1 box. This answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream/24890903#24890903) shows a good difference between them.

Comment: Thank you, your contribution is much appreciated! One remark, though: Comments like this typically go to the "comments" section of that specific answer. It's easier for keeping an overview that way. :)